# How to manage multiple currencies in the database

Tags: sql-server, database, domain-driven-design, currency, finance

If I have different multiple payroll disbursements based on the company location, the employee contract type and other criteria:
So

---

Some have their salaries divided into parts the first in USD and the second in Local cur.

```
Ex: Employee 343 receive his salary as following: 200 USD & 3000 EGP (The local currency).
EX: Employee 672 receive his salary as following: 200 USD & 200 EUR (The local currency).
```

Some have their salaries just in one currency (the local).

```
Ex: Employee 532 receive his salary as following: 5000 EGP.
```

So We have multiple currencies for the salaries of the company based on the location and other business rules.

What 's the most proper way to save the salaries of the employees with these variations in DB so that It's easy to retrieve, process and scale.

If I use one table so I will have many columns and I have to add new columns every time a new branch for the company is initiated.
Like this:

```
Sal_USD  | Sal_EGP | Sal_Eur
```

Is there an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Denormalization wouldn't be so great here. It's better to have a `currency_code` column or something equivalent.

Comment: @plalx Could U explain more please

Comment: Rather than scaling horizontally (adding columns) you scale vertically (add rows). You'd most likely have at least `employee_id`, `amount` and `currency_code`, where `currency_code` is USD, EGP, EUR, etc.

Comment: Do you understand the suggestion? Is this resolved?

Comment: @plalx : yes I have applied what you have suggested to me two tables on for currencies and the other I save one record for each amount. Thanks a lot You are the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is always to support an infinite numbers of connections. So create a table with salary an another with currency.

I think 3tables would do the jobb

```
Employee (the one you have now)
- EmployeeID

Salary
 - SalaryID
 - EmployeeID
 - CurrencyID
 - Wage
 - Exchangerate ?

CurrencyID
 - CurrencyID
 - Name (USD/GDP/EUR....)
```

Then you simply join them in.

Answer (score 2):

Create a column CurrencyCode and use 2 rows for an employee that has salary paid in 2 currencies.